# "a compelling but failed case"

Tags: adjectives

*Maybe just as important, Avery had terrific legal representation from attorneys Dean Strang and Jerry Buting who presented a compelling but failed case for reasonable doubt.*

Don't you think that there is a word missing after the adjective "compelling"? I would understand for example: "…who presented a compelling defense strategy but failed…" Or is "compelling" the noun in the sentence?

Comment: Both "compelling" and "failed" are being used as adjectives to describe the case, with the latter being used to diminish the positive description the former gave it. Consider "a beautiful but cracked vase" or "a fun but time-consuming game".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I misunderstood the sentence. I thought that "failed" is the verb. They failed case…

Comment: The wording is slightly ambiguous for a non-native; I reckon even some native speakers would misparse that, so don't feel too bad about misunderstanding it. :) The writer could perhaps have said "a compelling but doomed case" to avoid readers thinking that failed was meant to be a past tense verb.

Comment: But then they might think "doomed" was past the tense of **deem** and that the words "the judge" were maybe missing :)  Your first comment  makes a very good answer.

Comment: I tend to avoid answering if I don't have links to provide, but who am I to argue with the one they call Tim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ***compelling*** and ***failed*** are being used as separate adjectives to describe the case, with the latter being used to diminish the positive description the former gave it. Consider other similar constructions that use the same logic:

> a beautiful but cracked vase
>
> a fun but time-consuming game
>
> a strict but fair teacher

Note that usually when you do this you would put the "positive" adjective first and then the "negative" one as it doesn't quite work the same way when you reverse them, unless you wanted to focus more on the negative aspect (as in my third example).